# Redis - SCAN return duplicated keys with cursor "4611686018427387905"

Tags: redis

I'm learning Redis and trying SCAN command. I follow SCAN example at https://kb.objectrocket.com/redis/scan-redis-command-examples-509.

I ran:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> MSET key1 value1 key2 value2 key3 value3 key4 value4 key5 value5 key6 value6 key7 value7 key8 value8 key9 value9 key10 value10 key11 value11 key12 value12 key13 value13 key14 value14 key15 value15 key16 value16 key17 value17 key18 value18 key19 value19 key20 value20
OK
```

and then:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SCAN 0
```

but I got:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SCAN 0
1) "4611686018427387905"
2)  1) "key17"
    2) "key4"
    3) "key4"
    4) "key4"
    5) "key4"
    6) "key4"
    7) "key4"
    8) "key4"
    9) "key4"
   10) "key4"
127.0.0.1:6379> get key3
"value3"
127.0.0.1:6379> get key4
"value4"
127.0.0.1:6379> get key8
"value8"
```

then I tried next scan, and got:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SCAN 4611686018427387905
1) "4611686018427387905"
2)  1) "key4"
    2) "key4"
    3) "key4"
    4) "key4"
    5) "key4"
    6) "key4"
    7) "key4"
    8) "key4"
    9) "key4"
   10) "key4"
```

My result when using SCAN is not right, I think. I also try getting keys, it returned right value but SCAN did not.

Is it bug or I did something wrong? I'm running Redis 6.2.6.2 on Windows.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the official [SCAN](https://redis.io/commands/scan) command Redis documentation

> A given element may be returned **multiple** times. It is up to the application to handle the case of duplicated elements

Regarding `SCAN` return values, also from official docs

> As you can see the SCAN return value is an array of two values: the first value is the new cursor to use in the next call, the second value is an array of elements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have any idea about the cursor value "4611686018427387905"?

Comment: I have edited the answer, that value is the new cursor to use in the next `SCAN` call. `SCAN 4611686018427387905`

Comment: I tried next scan `SCAN 4611686018427387905` and got almost the same as first scan. I also edit my question with next scan result.